# Table populated by MySQL database get cell data and send it to another PHP page

Tags: html, mysql

I am trying to learn SQL and have it working. Now I am trying to add functionality of a table. I want to be able to click on a cell in the table and get its contents and send it to another PHP page as a variable to be used.

```
$q = "SELECT SuperBowl AS super, YearPlayed as year, Winner AS winner, Loser as loser, Score as score  FROM superbowl ORDER BY YearPlayed DESC";        
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query.
if ($result) { // If it ran OK, display the records.
    // Table header.
    echo '<table>
    <tr><th>Superbowl</th><th>Year Played</th><th>Winner</th><th>Loser</th><th>Score</th></tr>';
    // Fetch and print all the records:
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['super'] . '</td><td>' . $row['year'] . '</td><td>'. $row['winner'] . '</td><td>'. $row['loser'] . '</td><td>'. $row['score'] . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
        mysqli_free_result ($result); // Free up the resources.
} else { // If it did not run OK.
    // Public message:
        echo '<p class="error">The current users could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
} // End of if ($r) IF.
mysqli_close($dbcon); // Close the database connection.
```

The page is http://www.911techhelp.com/SuperBowl/ViewTeams.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok use this one. not the one i gave you before

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>h</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("td").click(function(){
                var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());
                window.location.replace("http://www.911techhelp.com/SuperBowl/super.php?" + $th.text() + '=' + $(this).text());
            });
        });
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: window.location.replace("http://www.911techhelp.com/SuperBowl/super.php?" + $th.text() + '=' + $(this).text()) to window.location.replace("http://www.911techhelp.com/SuperBowl/super.php?" + yearPick + '=' + $(this).text())

Comment: I meant window.location.replace("http://www.911techhelp.com/SuperBowl/super.php?" + 'yearPick'  + '=' + $(this).text())

Answer (score 0):

I dont have localserver installed currently so I have not tested it but this should work. This will post like that h=Hi or D=Hello.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>h</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("td").click(function(){
                var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());
                console.log($th.text() + '=' + $(this).text());
                $.ajax({
                    data: $th.text() + '=' + $(this).text(),
                    url: 'url_where_php_is_located.php',
                    method: 'POST', // or GET
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I have added the code and when I click anywhere in the table I get nothing.

Comment: Before I edited it from post to get I got an alert box. But now nothing

Comment: Have you changed the url_where_php_is_located.php to your page .

Comment: This  is the page that is used when I use the dropdown box to select year

Comment: I also changed the variable name to yearPicked which is what the page is looking for

Comment: like this www.911techhelp.com/SuperBowl/super.php?year=1995

Comment: just put the source code for you pages i will update what is required

Comment: Okay so I had to change the variable name in a few more places (duh) now I opened a console in google and I am getting the year when I click on it but it is saying I have an error in my SQL. I am playing with it but it works using the dropdown box. Will continue to check other things but thanks I am much further along now.

Comment: You can also use redirect by the way. Now I think of it i should have put that one.

Comment: What do you mean redirect

Comment: I will definitely mark as helped but can you please tell me what you mean use redirect cause I am still not getting desired results.

Comment: the other answer i gave you. I use redirect. For example from your table page you click on year. then a function is called. this function sends you to super.php with info if year such as this super.php?year=1997

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163523/discussion-between-andam-and-user2014572).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $_GET['yearPick'];
$q = "SELECT * FROM superbowl WHERE YearPlayed = $query ORDER BY YearPlayed DESC";      
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query.
if ($result) { // If it ran OK, display the records.

// Fetch and print fields into page:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $win = $row[Winner] . ".jpg"; //append .jpg to winning team name which is the name of pic to be displayed
    $lose = $row[Loser] . ".jpg"; //append .jpg to losing team name which is the name of pic to be displayed
    echo  "<div style='float:left';> <p><img src='images/$win' width='314px' height='272px' alt='winner'></p><p> <b>Year:</b>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $row[YearPlayed] . '</p>';
    echo  "<p> <b>Winner:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $row[Winner] . '</p>';
    echo  "<p> <b>Winning QB:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $row[WinningQB] . '</p>';
    echo  "<p> <b>Score:</b>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $row[Score] . '</p></div>';
    echo  "<div style='float:right';><p><img src='images/$lose' width='314px' height='272px' alt='loser'></p><p><b>Superbowl:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; " . $row[SuperBowl]. '</p>';
    echo  '<b>Loser:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ' . $row[Loser]. '</p>';
    echo  '<b>Losing QB:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ' . $row[LosingQB]. '</p>';
    echo  "<p> <b>City Played:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $row[CityPlayed] . '</p></div>';
    }
    mysqli_free_result ($result); // Free up the resources.
} else { // If it did not run OK.
// Public message:
    echo '<p class="error">The current records could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
    // Debugging message:
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
} // End of if ($r) IF.
mysqli_close($dbcon); // Close the database connection.
```